# Selenium ChromeDriver - Muting a tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to mute a tab? Meaning shutting its audio. I was trying to come out from

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (m_chromeWebdriver.getWindowHandles());
m_chromeWebdriver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

and to work on the tab, but I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1):

You can mute all tabs using

```
from selenium import webdriver

# in Chrome:
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

# in FireFox
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("media.volume_scale", "0.0")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392479/how-to-mute-all-sounds-in-chrome-webdriver-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't interact with the browser UI. The only way you might be able to do it indirectly is if there were a keyboard shortcut but I haven't seen one.

Comment: I would expect Selenium to deal with at least alsmost every Chrome feature. But maybe it is really not supported yet...

Comment: I must say that I disable the plugin but it always launches again when I run my code... :(

Comment: Selenium will not ever support browser specific UI elements. That's not it's intent. The intent of Selenium is to automate interactions with the webpage that happens to be hosted in a particular browser.

Comment: @Confiqure ...yes it does.  This answer explains why there is no way to do what OP asked.

Comment: @Confiqure The question is, "Is there a way to mute a tab?" and the answer is, No. I just explained why the answer is no and gave a possible (but unlikely) workaround.