# Mute a tab or entire browser with selenium in NodeJS (firefox)

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

How would I go about muting a tab or entire browser with NodeJS `selenium-webdriver` module in firefox
I can't find any docs or any methods on how to do this **for javascript**

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392479/how-to-mute-all-sounds-in-chrome-webdriver-with-selenium this should solve. If you can find Firefox's audio mute flag, you can apply it to geckodriver (shouldn't be too diff from the chromium one).

Comment: Ok thanks I'll have a look at that