# How can I mute the browser/tab in selenium using the geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to mute the browser/tab in selenium since headless mode doesnt mute sounds, I've searched but all I could find was chrome solutions and they didn't work, Also I don't want to use a profile

Is this possible on firefox/geckodriver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392479/how-to-mute-all-sounds-in-chrome-webdriver-with-selenium

Comment: @medium-dimensional Yeah I guess, I can mute the video elements, but it'd be more convenient to have an option that mutes all sounds on firefox

Comment: May this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400432/7789963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `set_preference("media.volume_scale", "0.0")` in `webdriver.FirefoxProfile()` class

Code:

```py
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("media.volume_scale", "0.0")
```

Full code example:

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("media.volume_scale", "0.0")
    
    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUVcZfQe-Kw")
```

For Selenium V4:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference("media.volume_scale", "0.0")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUVcZfQe-Kw")
```

Comment: Thank you! I made an edit for selenium V4 since `firefox_profile` is deprecated